# Irreducible group representation of subgroup

Tags: representation-theory

Does exist a way such that given $G$ a finite group, $H\leq G$ and $GL(V)$  build a group representation over $G$ (let's call it) $\rho\colon G \rightarrow GL(V)$ such that $H$ has an irreducible representation and $G$ not necessarily? In that case, does exist a way to make that any conjugation of $\rho(H)$ with elements of $\rho(G)$ be an irreducible representation?

Comment: For an irreducible representation $V$ of $H$, the induced representation $\uparrow^G V$ is not irreducible in general.

Comment: What is an irreducible representation $V$ of $H$? (I'm not familiarized with the topic)

Comment: Just an irrep $H \to GL(V)$.

Comment: So I can induce a representation given an irreducible representation of $H$ over $GL(V)$? In what book can I read about the construction of it?

Comment: Any book on representation theory should cover induced and restricted representations. There's an explicit formula for it, but the induced representation is basically just a tensor product.

Answer (score 1):

As @anomaly said, for an irreducible representation V of H, its induction in general is not irreducible. There is a criterion to determine the irreducibility of the induction representation, which is called Mackey's theorem(I don't sure whether the name of criterion is correct or not, but this criterion is actually due to Mackey).

For your second question, I can't understand it. And I am sorry that I can't answer it.